# Trigger Power Automate based on date condition is not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I want to trigger a Power Automate when the user enters today or past date but not with the future date. I have the below condition:

```
@lessOrEquals(triggerBody()?['ProjectClosedDate'],formatDateTime(utcnow(),'mm/dd/yyyy'))
```

The above condition is triggering the flow with the current date and past date which is expected but also triggering the flow when the user enters the future date. What could be wrong with the condition?

Comment: Are you converting the project close date to format just as that of current date mm/dd/yyyy.

Comment: Yes, I am converting the ProjectClosedDate to mm/dd/yyyy